# Free SSH GUI client with ssh tunnel support for Yosemite?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, ssh

Is there any free SSH GUI client for Mac OS X? Coming from Windows I would be happy with something as simple as Putty.

Features:

1. Free
2. Connection Manager
3. SSH tunnel support
4. Yosemite ready (and retina pretty)
5. Currently active (development not dead)
6. Support for private key authentication

I’m aware of similar questions posted here but I haven’t found a good alternative covering the requirements in items 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: iTerm profiles can be set up covering  2 and 4 and ssh itself supports 3 and 6 Terminal.app itself does all these

Comment: What Mark said. covered here as well. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52096/is-there-a-gui-ssh-client-for-os-x/52101#52101

Answer (score 2):

Most OS X users don't use "ssh GUIs" because OS X ships with a very good [Terminal application](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line). This is unlike Windows where the cmd.exe or even a PowerShell are not friendly command line interfaces to remote servers.

In OS X, you can just fire up Terminal.app and ssh from the command line with:

```
ssh <myhost>
```

You can use a more advanced terminal application like [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) and it will allow you to save "profiles" that, when called up, automatically run a set of commands in the terminal for you. You can use these to automatically start ssh connections (which can be interactive terminal sessions or stunnels):

[image]

You can start and stop stunnels from the command line as well -- after all, these are just ssh connections that open a local port and forward requests to a remote server. For example:

```
ssh -f user@personal-server.com -L 2000:personal-server.com:25 -N
```

And you're done.

Private key authentication schemes are supported by the ssh command line that ships, default, with any OS X version.

Answer (score 1):

You may try iTerm2

```
sudo port install iterm2
```

or

```
brew cask install iterm2
```

Comment: Once you have sufficient reputation, please put suggestions and clarifications into a comment. It is easy to get 50 reputation. If you have an answer, make sure to be specific ;)