# How to store SSH Credentials in Terminal

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, password, login

I am new to the MacBook and I am running El Capitan.

I'm migrating my machine usage from a PC to a MacBook. I am long time user of PuTTY and SuperPuTTY on a PC.

I want to create and save login credentials to my web servers in MacBook Terminal just like I've done in SuperPuTTY on the PC.

Is it possible to save web server login credentials in Mac Terminal?

**Here is My Overall Objective:**

I would like to know if there is an easy way in Mac Terminal to store the following command line login credentials and then use some sort of a shortcode to connect to my web server through Terminal:

```
ssh -p 2200 root@123.456.789.012
Password: ****************************************************************
```

I manage and connect to 5 different web servers so sorting out and organizing the login credentials in a short/fast connection method would be a huge time saver. Especially because my passwords are cryptic 64-character strings.

Comment: I've purged the comments as Tammy's edit version three knocked this out of the park in terms of clarity and usefulness. Well done!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can copy your public key to the remote machines. As long as they have public key authentication enabled, and your public key is present on the remote machine, you can `ssh` to the machines without having to supply a password.

First you'll need to generate a public/private keypair like so:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Follow the prompts. When it asks if you want to protect the key with a passphrase say YES! It's bad practice to not password-protect your keys and I'll show you how to only have to enter the password once in a while.

If you already have keypair you can skip the step above.

Now, assuming your ssh key exists on your Mac as `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, you can install it on a remote machine by running:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

For your specific server example cited above, the command would look like:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p 2200 root@123.456.789.012 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

You'll have to enter the password for `root@123.456.789.012` to perform this copy, but this should be the last time you need to do this. Assuming the remote server's `sshd` is setup to do public-private key authentication, when you ssh to the box now it shouldn't ask you for a password for the `root` account -- instead it'll ask you for the password for your *key*. Read on for how to make this something you don't need to enter all the time.

Repeat the above for every machine you want to ssh in to with your keys instead of a password.

**Please note, *anyone* who gets a hold of your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file can ssh to this machine as `root` without supplying a password for the remote machine. Password protecting the key file ensure they'd need to know the password for that key to use it. Make sure that file is secure. Use disk encryption on your Mac and keep the permissions on the file and the `~/.ssh/` directory tight.**

To make it easier to use the key without having to enter the password every time, OS X runs an `ssh-agent` process in the background on your machine. This agent will cache the keypair the first time you use it so you only have to enter your password once in a while. If you only sleep your mac, never restart it, you can go long periods of time without needing to enter your password.

You can pre-cache all your SSH keys with the `ssh-agent` by running:

```
ssh-add
```

Now you only need to remember the *key* password, not the many different account passwords. I usually keep my key passwords in [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) (no affiliation), further simplifying how many passwords I need to remember. Then I just look them up in 1Password and cut-and-paste them in the Terminal the odd time I restart my Mac and cause my running `ssh-agent` to be restarted.

If you combine copying your key to remote machines [with the Terminal.app connection management solution in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52096/is-there-a-gui-ssh-client-for-os-x), you'll have something very close to PuTTY for GUI connection experience.

---

On the server side, check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

is enabled in the configuration (it is by default in OpenSSH). You may also wish to set:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

While you're there so password-based authentication is disabled and keys become the only way to access the machine.

You'll need to restart sshd on the machine if you make any changes to the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks @IamC - this answer is great and I am sure will work. I created a stack exchange account here on the Mac Channel this morning to see if I could find a **quick** and **easy** way to save login credentials in Terminal or on the Mac somehow. It looks like doing so is extremely complicated and not a viable solution for me. Here's why: <more>

Comment: <cont.> I have command line access to a number of web servers (5 in all). I have a desktop PC at my work office with SSH (via PuTTY) access to these web servers. I have a *large* laptop PC at my home office with SSH (via PuTTY) access to these web servers. I just bought a MacBook Air for travel and on-site client visits. It's perfect for that particular need. I was hoping to make SSH connections to the servers as easy as it is through PuTTY and SuperPuTTY on the PC. <more>

Comment: <cont.> But I cannot go through the public auth key route because I would need to change the way PuTTY works on my home and work office PC's. It has become too daunting of a task to make the Mac work like my PC's so I think I will just have to stick with the copy & paste process for connecting from my Mac. Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate your helping me try to make my process simpler.

Comment: It's great answer @IanC and I am sure will help other standalone Mac users.

Comment: @tammy you can leave `PasswordAuthentication yes` on the server-side and PuTTY will continue to function as it always has on your Windows machine. This isn't an either/or scenario -- you can allow both types of authentication on the server. PuTTY also supports public/private key authorization like this FWIW. You can copy your `~/.ssh/id_rsa*` files to your Windows machine and import them in to PuTTY for authentication to the server. PuTTY, under the hood, uses the exact same OpenSSH libraries to connect as `ssh` on OS X.

Comment: For copying your key to a server, the `ssh-copy-id` command is easier: `ssh-copy-id user@example.com`. It's not installed by default on OS X, but it's just a `brew` away...

Comment: I think it bears mentioning that OS X has ssh-agent set up and enabled by default, and will offer to add keys you use to it automatically. Manual ssh-agent configuration is absolutely not required.

Comment: @AndrewMedico good point. I've removed the `.bash_profile` stuff and noted that OS X runs the agent for you.

Comment: `ssh-add` still works even in Sierra (OS X 10.12). Thanks

Comment: If anyone is looking to save/cache it to their Mac keychain like I was, you can use `ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 8):

You can use sshpass to save the password and won't have to insert everytime which isn't a good practice (security issues).

Follow the instructions for mac os x installation on : https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979

When you have sshpass installed run `sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@123.456.789.012:2200`

do the same thing for your 5 web servers and you won't need to insert the password everytime.

Comment: I feel way too dumb on this one. I guess using a PC with PuTTY and SuperPuTTY just distanced me too far from the base command line. I edited my OQ with my overall objective. Have a look.

Comment: I'm assuming now that you can get connected to root@123.456.789.012 and just want to automate the process. You basically don't want to type  each time `ssh -p 2200 root@123.456.789.012` and `Password: **********************` ?

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` isn't part of the standard OS X distribution.

Comment: @IanC. I think i forgot that i installed it with brew. will modify my answer

Comment: You got it @maetsoh -- that's exactly what I want to achieve here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this answer @maetsoh but once I looked at **Installing on OS X** (http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.xcode.html) my hair stood on end :) I think I'll just type passwords, etc. or find some other work around as getting to streamlining this process is getting way too complicated down this path. But thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the public/private key stuff, the .ssh/config file can be configured to ease use of ssh commands, like aliases, defaut user/port per server, ssh options, proxy commands...

Basically anything complicated you can put in a ssh command can be in this file too.

Answer (score 0):

I have ported Putty to Mac as a native application bundle, so no need for macports or terminals if your not a technical user.

More information with screen-shots is here : http://www.wine-reviews.net/2016/08/putty-for-mac-os-x-now-available.html

Cheers,

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Be sure to answer the question directly. If I you mention a product you work on, that's fine, but try to be on topic as opposed to pasting the same marketing blurb on multiple posts.