# How do I ensure SMB based volume paths are available?

Tags: terminal, smb

My machine is `mymac` and the remote machine is `remotemac`(both are running El Capitan 10.11.6) - I reference a share on `remotemac`, located at //remotemac/path/to/remoteshare, as /Volumes/remoteshare.

Sometimes, especially when I have recently connected to that remote machine or  share from Finder, the /Volumes/remoteshare path is available. But after some time, that /Volumes/remoteshare path is not available.

```
$ ls /Volumes
Macintosh HD
$ # connect to remoteshare from Finder
$ ls /Volumes
$ Macintosh HD    remoteshare
# After some time (a few hours)...
$ ls /Volumes
Macintosh HD 
$ # note that /Volumes/remoteshare is now missing
```

What can I do in my bash script to ensure that the remoteshare volume is present, or created before it is referenced?

Answer (score 1):

In a script you can use the following basic construct:

```
#!bin/bash

if mount | grep -q "remoteshare"; then # check if remoteshare is available 
    exit
else
    echo not found
fi
```

`grep -q ...` suppresses normal output. If successful the script exits. In the other case it will echo "not found".

Instead of `echo not found` you can ssh into the remote server, run `serveradmin` and enable or restart the smb service – `man serveradmin` will show you how to do this. Then quit the ssh session and try to remount the SMB share.

To ssh passwordless into the server [enable key based authentication](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210133/93229) - passing a password in a script is insecure and error prone. To use `serveradmin` on the remote server without sudoing, modify /etc/sudoers on the remote server and change the part:

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to

```
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
your_remote_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/serveradmin
```

Instead of the line `echo not found` use something like this then:

```
ssh username@remotemac
serveradmin stop smb
sleep 10
serveradmin start smb
sleep 2
exit
echo "SMB service was restarted"
mount_smbfs //your_remote_username:password@remotemac/folder /some/mntpoint
```

---

The inaccessibility of an SMB share may have many causes. It's probably impossible to cover all cases in one script.

Comment: Thanks - this alternative sounds insecure - I am essentially trusting my user name to ssh into the remote machine - how does Finder manage to open the remote share when I click on the (remotemac) share link in Finder sidebar? Does it use sudo?  I would like to make my script be as secure as that experience.

Comment: @Anand key based ssh authentication is usually more secure than password based auth.

Comment: Agreed, I am trying to understand how Finder does it (and do the same). Obviously Finder on my client does not require these edits to the remote machine settings - any client Finder window in the network is able to find the shares I am looking for.

Comment: @Anand you can also include Apple Script in your bash script with ...osascript.. and use the FInder

Comment: I was just looking into AppleScript to do this :-) Could you post a solution for this that uses AppleScript within bash? Thanks!

Comment: @Anand I don't know whether Server.app is scriptable or not - I don't think it's as easy as the cli. The problem here is, that I don't know what's wrong with the SMB server. The spontaneous unmounts may be a time-out or a smb/OS X bug.

Comment: Thanks. This issue is fairly consistent - after some time (at least a few minutes), with no finder window connected to the remote, the volumes just disappear - this has been happening for a while now, at least as far back as Yosemite.